# C Null character causing problems with program behaviour

Tags: c, arrays

The problem I am having is that this program is menu driven. When I enter the letter "i" is inputted in the `input` array which has a size of `MAX_LENGTH+1`. Through GDB I found out that "i" is inputted in the 0th index of the `input` array and the rest of the spaces are inputted with the `NULL_CHAR` character. Anyways when I press "i" for the insert menu, I have greeted by a field which tells me to enter a value. I enter any integer and press inter. Instead of being greeted by the "Command?:" field and give me a chance to put an entry, it immediately tells me that my input is invalid and tells me to enter a command again. Here is what I mean:

```
Commands are I (insert), D (delete), S (search by name),
  V (search by value), P (print), Q (quit).

Command?: i
45

Command?: 
Invalid command.
Commands are I (insert), D (delete), S (search by name),
  V (search by value), P (print), Q (quit).


Command?:
```

I found out that the reason this is happening is because when the safegets function is called again, for some reason the local variable `c` in the function safegets has a value of `NULL_CHAR`, presumably from the fact that all the other values in the input char array had all other entries as `NULL_CHAR`. I do not understand why `c` is automatically assigned the value of NULL_CHAR because in the while loop, because there's a statement `c = getchar()` that should be asking for my input again. But for some reason after every entry, `c`'s default value becomes NULL_CHAR and asks you for your input the next time `safegets` is called.

Here is my what I want my output to be like:

```
Commands are I (insert), D (delete), S (search by name), 
  V (search by value), P (print), Q (quit). 
 
Command?: I 
  value: 50000 
 
Command?: I
  value:
```

Here is the main function:

```
const int MAX_LENGTH = 1023;
const char NULL_CHAR = '\0';
const char NEWLINE = '\n';


    int main (void)
    { 
        const char bannerString[]
            = "Personal Team Maintenance Program.\n\n";
        const char commandList[]
            = "Commands are I (insert), D (delete), S (search by name),\n"
              "  V (search by value), P (print), Q (quit).\n";

        // Declare linked list head.
        //   ADD STATEMENT(S) HERE TO DECLARE LINKED LIST HEAD.


        // announce start of program
        printf("%s",bannerString);
        printf("%s",commandList);

        char response;
        char input[MAX_LENGTH+1];
        int value;
        do
        {
            printf("\nCommand?: ");
            safegets(input,MAX_LENGTH+1);
            // Response is first char entered by user.
            // Convert to uppercase to simplify later comparisons.
            response = toupper(input[0]);

            if (response == 'I')
            {
                // Insert a player entry into the linked list.
                // Maintain the list in correct order (G, D, M, S).
                //   ADD STATEMENT(S) HERE

                // USE THE FOLLOWING PRINTF STATEMENTS WHEN PROMPTING FOR DATA:
                // printf("  family name: ");
                // printf("  first name: ");
                // printf("  position: ");
                   printf(" value: ");
                   scanf("%d", value);






            }
            else if (response == 'D')
            {
                // Delete a player from the list.

                printf("\nEnter family name for entry to delete: ");

                //   ADD STATEMENT(S) HERE

            }
            else if (response == 'S')
            {
                // Search for a player by family name.

                printf("\nEnter family name to search for: ");

                //   ADD STATEMENT(S) HERE

            }
            else if (response == 'V')
            {
                // Search for players that are worth less than or equal a value.

                printf("\nEnter value: ");

                //   ADD STATEMENT(S) HERE

            }
            else if (response == 'P')
            {
                // Print the team.

                //   ADD STATEMENT(S) HERE

            }
            else if (response == 'Q')
            {
                ; // do nothing, we'll catch this case below
            }
            else 
            {
                // do this if no command matched ...
                printf("\nInvalid command.\n%s\n",commandList);
            }
        } while (response != 'Q');

        // Delete the whole linked list that hold the team.
        //   ADD STATEMENT(S) HERE


        // Print the linked list to confirm deletion.
        //   ADD STATEMENT(S) HERE


        return 0;
    }
```

Helper function being called:

```
void safegets (char s[], int arraySize)
{
    int i = 0, maxIndex = arraySize-1;
    char c;
    while (i < maxIndex && (c = getchar()) != NEWLINE)
    {
        s[i] = c;
        i = i + 1;
    }
    s[i] = NULL_CHAR;
}
```

Comment: Why do you try to hide `\0` and `\n` behind some custom names? While it is good practice to avoid magic constants, they are none such.

Comment: This is typically not called the "null character", but instead a "terminating null".

Comment: Please only provide the least amount of code that demonstrates your issue(s).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine. You need to change

```
scanf("%d", value); 
//          ^Place & before the argument value because scanf expect pointer as its argument
```

to

```
scanf("%d", &value);
```

Answer (score 0):

If fix ze code fer ewe

```
      else 
        {
            // do this if no command matched ...
            if (response != '\0')
              printf("\nInvalid command.\n%s\n",commandList);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem with your code is that you are not emptying the input buffer after you calls to `scanf` (such as if and 'I' is entered and 'value' is read. After each call to `scanf` you will still have a carriage return and/or a newline in the input buffer. The next call to `safegets` sees input still in the input buffer and reads it. To fix it, empty the input buffer after each call to `scanf`:

```
char strip;

. . .

if (response == 'I')
{
    printf(" value: ");
    scanf("%d", value);

    /* empty the input buffer after scanf */
    do {
        strip = getchar();
    } while (strip != '\n');

    printf

}
```