# Program (C) crashing when using switch statement and functions

Tags: c, function, crash, switch-statement

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void play();
void quit();

int main()
{
    int x;
    printf("1) play\n2) quit\n");
    scanf("%d", x);
    switch(x) {
    case(1): {
        play();
        break;
    }
    case(2): {
        quit();
        break;
    }
    default:{
        printf("BAD INPUT");
        break;
    }

    /*if x is equal to 1, play
      if x is equal to 2, quit
      otherwise, tell the user, BAD INPUT*/
}

return 0;
}

void play(void){
    printf("play");
}

void quit(void){
   printf("quit");
}
```

So basically, I am trying to get it so that if the user enters 1, it says play, and if the user enters 2, it says quit. It prints play and quit, but as soon as I enter a number and press enter the whole thing just crashes. I have searched far and wide, but I just can't figure out why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24417407/2455888) will help you to find the problem.

Comment: You should get compiler warnings... [For example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7cd9e21f53462bc8)

Comment: Wow thanks XD. I feel like an idiot now.

Answer (score 1):

mis-usage of `scanf`

Line: `scanf("%d", x);`

should be `scanf("%d", &x);`